Exception in HostFunction: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libhermes.so" not found
I was trying to upgrade my react-native project to android 14, but during run time, I am getting runtime error. Error: Exception in HostFunction: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libhermes.so" not found: needed by /data/app/~~-JbImBbjHIYK06Wm5VDeFA==/package-G4oyNZDyg6x_sn_SRraUIA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a/libreanimated.so in namespace clns-7
react-native 0.71.16
react-native-reanimated 2.17.0
openjdk 18.0.2 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-18.0.2.9.1 (build 18.0.2+9-FR)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-18.0.2.9.1 (build 18.0.2+9-FR, mixed mode, sharing)
compileSdkVersion 34
targetSdkVersion 34
kotlinVersion "1.9.0"
